# problem with exec'ing python sqlite3 execute command

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

while I'm actually hoping to get a more complex query going, I have the following (working) query (in 3.8 python):

```
aa =  conn2.execute("select proj from (select distinct proj from \
      top_table group by proj) where proj = \'xx\' group by proj;")
```

This returns an object I can run `fetchall()` on. But when I try and use `exec`, making:

```
aa =  exec ("conn2.execute(\"select proj from (select distinct proj \
      from top_table group by proj) where proj = \'%s\' group by proj;\")" % t)
```

where `t ='xx', aa` returns `Nonetype`. Also, when I swap `print` for `conn2.execute` and end up with:

```
aa =  exec ("print(\"select proj from (select distinct proj from \
      top_table group by proj) where proj = \'%s\' group by proj;\")" % t)
```

it returns:

```
select proj from (select distinct proj from top_table group by proj)\
where proj = 'xx' group by proj;
```

Which I can paste into an sqlite3 shell and get a proper value returned.

has anyone experienced an issue like this when using sub-queries with the `exec` command?

Note, there might be too many group/distinct statements for most people's taste, but this was cut down from a much longer command, and it runs as is (just not with exec).

Comment: why do you need `exec()` ? Why you don't use normal string formatting to create Query? Or maybe you should put `t` normally as parameter - `execute(QUERY, args=(t,))` and it will put it in correct place.

Comment: btw: `print()` sends text on screen and always return `None` so using `print()` is useless. Maybe better learn how to correctly use `execute()` or how to format string.

Comment: print() was just illustrating the string after the variable substitution, showing that a valid command was being sent to execute(). And you're right, I didn't seem to need exec in this case. I just tend to use it on that type of string substitution because a) it's one less step than formatting the string separately and b) I sometimes use string substitution to build commands and run them, so I'm just used to using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, using `exec` is the dumbest idea.

---

You could use even normal string formatting - `"text '{}' text".format(t)`

```
query = """select proj from 
           (select distinct proj from top_table group by proj) 
           where proj = '{}' group by proj;""".format(t)
```

or f-string - `f"text '{t}' text"`

```
query = f"""select proj from 
            (select distinct proj from top_table group by proj) 
            where proj = '{t}' group by proj;"""
```

eventually old `%` - `"text '%s' text" % t`

```
query = f"""select proj from 
            (select distinct proj from top_table group by proj) 
            where proj = '%s' group by proj;""" % t
```

and later use it

```
conn2.execute(query)
```

---

But better check if it will work with arguments in `execute` - it should put `t` in place of `?`

```
query = """select proj from 
           (select distinct proj from top_table group by proj) 
           where proj = ? group by proj;"""

conn2.execute( query, (t,) )
```

it has to be tuple even if you have only one parameter - `(t,)`

You may also try dictionary with parameters and it should put `t` in place of `:value`

```
query = """select proj from 
           (select distinct proj from top_table group by proj) 
           where proj = :value group by proj;"""

conn2.execute( query, {'value': t} )
```

Using `?` and `:value` it should add `' '` automatically and you don't have to use it.

SQLite documentation: [execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)